# Select element inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have something like this:

```
var SucessList = [
 {
  id: 1,
  dedicated: true
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  dedicated: false
 }
];
```

and I want to make an if function to check if dedicated == true. How do i select dedicated to use like that?

Comment: even easier than in the dupe.  `SuccessList.filter(v => v.dedicated);`

Comment: other methods available also depending on use case, which is not clear at all in question

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean by that? I intend to use an if else statement that checks if dedicated is true and give me a link and if false, gives me a different link. As said in other comment, I'm very new to js and it seems to me like a simple straight forward question. I guess I was wrong

Comment: well one case might be you only want to know if any of them are true and simply have a yes/no answer, or as in your case return specific data where that property is true. you didn't specify what expected results were

Comment: @charlietfl I did not know it was relevant, but yes, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

```
let res = SucessList.filter(({dedicated}) => dedicated);
```

Comment: side note: dont use this in a productional environment (ES6 isnt supported by some browsers)

Comment: Okay, let's assume I don't understand much about js, what do I do with that and how do I make my if else statement to check if dedicated it's true or false?

Comment: @jay.pepper `({dedicated})` pattern destructures current object to set identifier `dedicated` to the value of the `dedicated` property of that object. `.filter()` returns the element where `true` is return value of callback function. If `dedicated` is `true`, the current object is returned within `res` array, else current object is not set as an element of resulting `res` array. For example `let {dedicated} = {
  id: 1,
  dedicated: true
 }; console.log(dedicated)`.

Comment: @jay.pepper Does the description at previous comment help clarify the pattern utilized at Answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but even tho I'm sure you must be right, I don't have enough knowledge to fully understand your answer... I appreciate the effort very much

Comment: The solution is essentially the same as approach at [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964404/select-element-inside-array/41964488?noredirect=1#comment71107830_41964404) by @baao